# dr who The war doctor how does he fit into the whole story?

Tags: doctor-who

just a question i thought david tennant explained he was young when he ran away from gallifrey after exploding the daleks and them so why was it said the war doctor was the one who did it if he becomes chris ecelston in the regeneration and not be the first doctor?

Comment: Could you re-write your question to be a bit clearer? I can’t quite understand what you’re asking.

Comment: Can you remember which episode you remember David Tennant saying this? He may have said was young when he left Gallifrey at some point--you might be remembering "The Sound of Drums" when he talked about how Time Lords were shown the untempered schism as kids, and that 'Some would be inspired, some would run away, and some would go mad', and he said he was one of the ones that ran, although he didn't say that he ran *immediately*, and we saw in 'The Name of the Doctor' he ran when he was older. But he never said he was young when he ended the Time War by blowing up Gallifrey and the Daleks.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have misheard or misunderstood something that David Tennant's Doctor said, because you have his backstory rather badly wrong.

Christopher Eccleston was never the first Doctor. He was always, from his first appearance identified as the Ninth Doctor. We now know that he was technically the tenth distinct incarnation of The Doctor, but since The Doctor does not consider the John Hurt incarnation to be "a Doctor", that one doesn't get a number. That makes David Tennant the Tenth Doctor, Matt Smith the Eleventh, etc.

The Tenth Doctor, and his chief rival The Master, did frequently reveal parts of their childhood and history over the course of Tennant's tenure as The Doctor.  However, you have to be careful not to take things literally, especially when The Doctor says them. For example, at one point Ten explains how the Time Lords take young prospective Time Lords to see the Untempered Schism and gauge their reaction. The Master says this is where he started to go insane, and Ten says that his reaction was to run.

However, he does not literally mean that he ran away from Gallifrey right at that point; rather, he's being more figurative: he spent the rest of his life running from the responsibility of being a Time Lord.

He did not really leave Gallifrey until much, much later. We finally get to see that event occur in "The Name of The Doctor", when Clara enters his timeline. She visits all of his past incarnations and saves them from being destroyed by the Great Intelligence, and one of those scenes shows the First Doctor and his granddaughter Susan stealing a TARDIS from the repair shop.

As far as the basic timeline of The Doctor, there are decades worth of episodes that ran from the 60's through the late 80s that you would have to watch to get the full story, but the general idea is:

- At some point when he was *around* 200 years old (an estimate based on a handful of times The Doctor has given his age), the First Doctor and Susan stole a TARDIS and started romping around the universe.
- He eventually lands on Earth, the TARDIS gets stuck as a phone box, and he picks up additional companions. He begins to take those human companions exploring time and space, for the bulk of the next 1000+ years of his life. At first, these adventures have little or nothing to do with The Time Lords or Daleks or their war, with notable exceptions:

  - Very early on, he arrives on planet Skaaro and sees the Daleks for the first time. He would encounter them occasionally over the subsequent years, mostly foiling their plans to conquer the universe.
  - Some time later, the Time Lords send him (now the Fourth Doctor) back to the point where the Daleks were created. This episode, *The Genesis of the Daleks*, is frequently considered the greatest episode of classic Doctor Who, so if you can find it, I'd strongly recommend watching it. Most notably, this episode has been identified as the "opening shot" in the Time War.
- At some point during the Eighth Doctor's life, the Last Great Time War begins. Initially, The Doctor refuses to fight in this war, but at the end he is forced to recognize that he can't avoid it. This happens during the mini-episode "[The Night of The Doctor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U3jrS-uhuo)", during which Eighth Doctor (Paul McGann) regenerates into the War Doctor  (John Hurt).
- The War Doctor fights, ultimately decided that ending the war is worth the possible destruction of his own people, leading to the events of "The Day of The Doctor". At the end of that episode, War Doctor regenerates into the Ninth Doctor (Christoper Eccleston). For reasons explained in that episode, The Ninth Doctor's memory is of using the Moment to destroy all Daleks and all Time Lords (though we later learn that some Daleks managed to escape.)
- Very soon after that, we see the Ninth Doctor show up in London, in the episode "Rose", believing that he has just killed his own people and trying to run away from that fact.

Comment: _"He was always, from his first appearance identified as the Ninth Doctor"_ That's not true. Within the canon of the renewed series, this was not confirmed until Sarah Jane popped up and met Ten. (Even then, an argument could have been made for an altered backstory right up until we saw the journal in "Human Nature".)

Comment: He's always been the Ninth; confirmed or not. They didn't lay it out, unlike usual, and had the new audience discover The Doctor along side Rose (an interesting journey to be sure, for new and old)

Comment: Simple, he's the incarnation the 8th Doctor regenerated into to fight in the Time War (in other words the true 9th Doctor). See Night of The Doctor